# Get text from webpage using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, html-agility-pack

I would like to get the innertext from the tags < p >. I use HtmlAgilityPack to get the html code from the website. But this isn't working what am I doing wrong?

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml("urlwebsite");

var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")
                  .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: I'd suggest Fizzler with HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

Please try following

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc;
var web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
doc = web.Load("urlwebsite");

var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")
                  .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                  .ToList();
```